# Interceptor en Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

Greetings I am implementing an interceptor in Angular 9, when capturing when the idtoken is incorrect it generates the new tokens but the request is not sent again, the interceptor code is this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth:AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    console.log ("solicitud interceptada correctamente!"); 
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    let refreshToken = data['data'].refreshToken;
    console.log('refreshToken',refreshToken);

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
      console.log(err.error);
      if (err.error.code === 401) {
        console.log('Refresh Token');
          if (err.error.message == "Token no valido.") {
            console.log('Refresh Token');
            let refresh={
              "refreshToken":refreshToken
            }
            this.auth.getTokenRefresh(refresh)
            .subscribe(respt =>{
              // this.datar['data'].refreshToken=respt['data'].refreshToken;
              data['data'].idToken=respt['data'].idToken;
              data['data'].accessToken=respt['data'].accessToken;

              this.auth.guardarToken(respt['data'].idToken);
              this.auth.guardarRespuesta(data);
              console.log(respt);
              console.log("Datos Refrescar",data);
              console.log("Id token Refrescar",respt['data'].idToken);

              request = request.clone({ 
              setHeaders: { 
                'Application': 'UEhBTlRPTVhfV0VC',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${respt['data'].idToken}` 
              } 
              });   
              // this.router.navigate(['/seguridad/gestion-usuarios']);
            },(err) =>{
              // this.error=err.error['message'];
              // this.erroru=true;
              console.log(err.error);
            });
            return next.handle(request); 
              //TODO: Token refreshing
          }else {
              //Logout from account or do some other stuff
          }
      }
      return next.handle(request); 
      // return next.handle(request);
    }));
    
  }
}
```

I understand that the "return next.handle (request);" It generates the request again but I do not know why it is not made, I have been investigating a lot but I do not get a solution, I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

You should wait until the Refresh token API returns the response. If you don't know how to wait for http response before proceeding to next line of code, read about either "async and await" of "forkJoin".

Comment: How would I do it? I don't have much experience with await